# How to "devectorize" a vector array (nx100) into text using a pre-trained model in Word2Vec using Gensim?

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, gensim, word2vec

So I created a Word2Vec model using Gensim using a document. Then I did some calculations on the vector array which I obtained by punching the code `model[model.wv.vocab]`. 
Now I have a new vector array with me and I want to "devectorize" this new vector array into text. How can this be done in python?

Comment: `Word2Vec` places single words into a shared vector-space. If after your "punching" you've got a new vector, you can look up the existing words closest to that new vector via `model.wv.most_similar(positive=[new_vector])`. (Explicitly specifying the `positive` parameter helps the code recognize your value as a vector, not a list-of-lookup-keys.) If finding such a nearest-word isn't what you mean, please supply more detail in your question about your ultimate goals, perhaps with example inputs/your-code-so-far and desirable output.

Comment: Well, I have a document, and I vectorized each word/token of that document using Word2Vec into a model. I got a vector array (2D numpy array) which is just "quantified" form of that document. Now I did some calculations on that numpy array so that I end up with a new numpy array with new values. How to revert that numpy array back to text using that same model? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: What kind of calculations on that numpy array? What is its dimensions after your calcs? (Is it a single vector? Or if your document started with N words, and then you had N word-vectors, do you now have N other modified vectors?) What do you expect this "text" at the end to be? A single word? The same number of words as your input text? Some other meaningful sentence?

Comment: Initially, the dimensions of the vectorized document were nx100. After the calculations, it became mx100; where m<n. So basically, I have reduced the number of words and I am expecting to get a kind of summary of the original document. Yes, I know there are methods available on the internet to do that, but I need to come up with a unique algorithm to summarize a document for my project.

Comment: If you now have *m* 100-d vectors, and whatever your calculations were retained meaningfulness in the same 100-dimensional space, then you could look up the `most_similar()` word for each of those *m* new vectors. (If you want the resulting text to fit other constraints – like being a grammatical sentence – you'd have to go far beyond what `Word2Vec` alone provides.)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. And any suggestions for that grammatical thing you are talking about? What can I use for that?

Comment: Some deeper/recurrent neural networks can be trained to generate plausible text, or do "sequence to sequence" learning that changes an input text's language, tone, length, etc. A search on [neural network summarization] should turn up lots of relevant work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. BTW, is it possible with sentences also? I mean if I try to vectorize whole sentences instead of single words, what's the best way to do that, and also how to devectorize it after I perform my calculations?

Comment: `Word2Vec` doesn't directly convert full texts to single vectors – though people will sometimes average all the words of a text to get a single vector. Such a single vector can only map back to nearby single-words, though. The `Doc2Vec` (aka 'Paragraph Vector`) is a very word2vec-like algorithm that does work on longer texts – but there's no meaningful way to turn those vectors back to long texts. However, the deeper/recurrent and seq2seq networks can take long texts as input, and sometimes emit long texts as output.